# How to order INSERTs after TRIGGER-statements with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Okay guys, my problem is kind of a first world problem but it bugs me...

I'm designing my MySQL database with MySQL Workbench and after drawing all tables, triggers and `INSERT`s I let the Workbench generate the `CREATE`-SQL for me. That is really cool but here is the problem:

> One of my triggers is a `AFTER INSERT` trigger that relies on a `INSERT` I
>   defined in Workbench, too. But because the triggers are created after the `INSERT`s, the trigger doesn't fire.

Of course I can just open a text editor and copy all of my `INSERT`s after the triggers, but yeah thats the point that bugs me. I could also write a script, but my question is:

> Can I change the order of the exported `CREATE`-SQL in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: What is the error? Show us your script - CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER...

Comment: There is no error. The CREATE TRIGGER statements are just behind the INSERT statements and that is the reason why the triggers don't fire. So like I asked before I just wanted to change the order of the CREATE statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't reorder these statements.

Long answer: the INSERTs data in a model are not to be used as general data store for your database, they are simply not made for that. Their purpose is to allow entering test data after synchronisation/forward engineering. A better approach is to add a separate SQL script to your model (see the overview page for notes and scripts). Once you are done with your sync you can then use the script to run additional code. I have to admit however that the integration of those scripts is not so good currently. You have to copy the sql text and paste it in an editor of an open connection.

Comment: Hey thanks for that answer! Since I load the CREATE-script with another sync-tool it will be okay the load the additional script with the tool, too. I think I have to deal with that :) thanks again